# How to use Resource[] in spring to read files from windows file system specified in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use spring's Resource interface to read files from local machine using spring boot project. I specified the file path in application.properties

```
filePath=c/tmp/*.pdf
```

and trying to read using @value annotation in the code.

```
@Value("${filePath:}")
private Resource[] filePath;
```

However when I try to run the app its giving me the following error

> cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Can someone help me understand on how to properly read files from external folder which is not in a classpath and specified in application.properties file?

Comment: You should almost always prefer `List<Resource>` to `Resource[]`. It just makes life easier.

Comment: Need more information about your machine. Is this Windows? If so, why `c/tmp`? Do you have a full path? Have you tried `file:`?

Comment: Yes its a windows machine. I have my pdf files located in `c://tmp` folder. I just tried using file: infront of file path in application.properties 
Its giving me an empty array